# getting nested maps in Java

Tags: java, json

I've the below json code.

```
{
"main": {
    "temp": 301.335,
    "pressure": 951.08,
    "humidity": 45,
    "temp_min": 301.335,
    "temp_max": 301.335,
    "sea_level": 1025.43,
    "grnd_level": 951.08
  }
}
```

And I'm using the below java code to get this data.

This above json is stored in a String `text`.

```
            System.out.println(text);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // read JSON from a file
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });

        System.out.println(map.get("main"));

        Map<String, Object> mapIn = mapper.readValue(map.get("main").toString(),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });

        System.out.println(mapIn);
```

Here i want to print the `temp` value in my console. But as of now I get the below o/p with exception.

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 106.85,
    "lat": -6.21
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 802,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "scattered clouds",
    "icon": "03d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 304.15,
    "pressure": 1007,
    "humidity": 62,
    "temp_min": 304.15,
    "temp_max": 304.15
  },
  "visibility": 8000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.1,
    "deg": 320
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1478244600,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 8043,
    "message": 0.0084,
    "country": "ID",
    "sunrise": 1478211943,
    "sunset": 1478256397
  },
  "id": 1642911,
  "name": "Jakarta",
  "cod": 200
} {
  temp = 304.15, pressure = 1007, humidity = 62, temp_min = 304.15, temp_max = 304.15
}
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at Jackson2Example.main(Jackson2Example.java: 51)
```

please let me know where am I going wrong, how can I fix this and get `temp` value.

Thanks

Comment: why are you calling mapper.readValue again. This time you are calling it with String (not Json String).

Comment: @SachinGupta, this is where I'm stuck... unable to know how to get that `temp` from output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to call `mapper.readValue` again. try this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });


Map<String, Object> mainMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("main");        

System.out.println(mainMap.get("temp"));
```

Comment: Haa, now I got this, this would in turn get value from the nested json. Thank you verymuch...